# GRE Text Completion - choosing between Instigated and Prompted

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, gre

I came across the following two-blank text-completion question:

> The discovery that exposure to allergens through the mother's diet during the 
>   last trimester could lead to complications during the first year after birth 
>   ① ______ the UK Department of Health to ② _______ dietary recommendations
>   for expecting mothers

The options for ① are:

- prompted
- instigated
- lulled

The options for blank ② are:

- intuit
- codify
- officiate

I was able to rule out *lulled* for ① but I am stuck between choosing
*instigated* and *prompted*. The answer key is *codify* for ② (which is
pretty much as expected) and *prompted* for ①.

Why is *prompted* is a better fit here than *instigated*? Can anyone please
give more uses comparing these two words, explaining which one to use where?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Would you please edit your question to show us your research of "intuit" versus "codify"? It's the blank for part ii that makes "codify" better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Instigate* is a more loaded term that tends to take an action as its object. Here is its definition according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instigate):

> : to goad or urge forward : PROVOKE

*[Goading](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goad)* has a connotation of being led by someone else, irrespective of what the people affected think. (A rider's spur would be a goad.) I might *instigate* something, which means I urge that situation forward. In contrast *[prompt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prompted)* allows for more persuasion, for *moving someone to do an action*:

> 1 : to move to action : INCITE

The difference is visible in what tends to follow each verb in corpus results. I used a [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) comparison search for the verb forms of *instigate* and *prompt*, focusing on the two words following the verb. As shown below, *instigate* is often followed by an action (reform, conflicts, attacks, violence); *prompt* is often followed by the entity being moved to act (you, us, them, students, people, him).

[image]

So while one might *instigate* a reform, in your version a discovery *prompted the UK Department of Health* to do something.